# Do astronauts on ISS notice Earth's seasons?

Tags: iss, earth, astronaut-lifestyle

Has anyone stationed on the ISS for some months reported noticing the changing seasons on Earth in any way like people on the surface do, subconsciously without needing to look up numbers for anything?  Changing weather patterns, changing daylight hours in each hemisphere, how far north or south sunlight reaches?

Answer (score -3):

From the last thing I saw on the news: On December 1, it was reported that the air leak from the ISS was practically unnoticable for astronauts.
Astronauts who recently returned to Earth who were on the ISS before the coronavirus was discovered reported that isolation on the ISS is not as noticeable as isolation on Earth. Astronauts who will stay on the ISS for the New Year will celebrate the holiday 16 times, as they will cross 16 time zones on New Year's Eve. From the above information, we can conclude that it is difficult to notice the change of season on the ISS without observing time, and without observing the planet it is completely impossible. I have not seen any messages from astronauts about this.

Comment: do astronauts on the ISS not observe the planet? is it invisible to them? and do they not have clocks?

Comment: The conclusion does not follow from these premises.